# How do I change a timestamp (not UNIX) to a date and time in Excel/R?

Tags: r, excel, date

I am using a dataset that has time listed this way:

```
200901010000
200901010030
200901010100
```

For example, the first one represents Jan 1, 2009, hour 0, minute 0, and the last one represents Jan 1, 2009, hour 1, minute 0. Is there a fast way to change this to be listed as something usable? With the time in its current state, any time series I make gets distorted. Thanks!

Tried to change it to Date Time format in Excel but couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: `as.POSIXct(as.character(200901010000), format="%Y%m%d%H%M")`. Notable is this will not work if you use _numbers_, nor if your system (based on whatever options/configuration) chooses to display them using scientific notation. There are ways to work around that latter part if needed, perhaps using `sprintf`.

Comment: EXCEL: `=--TEXTJOIN({"-","-"," ",":"},,MID(A1,{1,5,7,9,11},{4,2,2,2,2}))` then format the output as the date style you want.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! Is there a way to apply the as.POSIXct function to the entire dataset? I tried using
as.POSIXct(as.character(df$TIMESTAMP_START), format="%Y%m%d%H%M")
but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: What didn't work?  Did you remember to reassign the value to the column of the data frame (i.e. `df$TIMESTAMP_START <- as.POSIXct(....)` ) ?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel:

```
B1: =--TEXT(A1,"0000\/00\/00 00\:00")
```

and format as a date, eg: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm`

[image]

The `TEXT` function returns the number as a string which Excel will recognize as a date/time.

The double unary `--` converts that into a number (which is how Excel stores datetimes.

Then it is just a matter of formatting that number properly.